# How can I apply the same set of values at various positions in a larger array, specified by masks?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, mask

I have a 2D array `Y` of dimensions `N x N`, and an array of `K` binary masks `X`, each of dimensions `M x M` (so, `X` has shape `K x M x M`). Each binary mask in `X` has exactly one `N x N` patch of ones, and the rest of the elements are zero. I would like to create a `K x M x M` array `Z`, with elements of `Y` in the locations specified by `X`, and zero everywhere else.

For example, if `M = 3`, `N = 2`, `K = 3`, and

```
X = [[[1., 1., 0.],
     [1., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 1., 1.],
     [0., 1., 1.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 1., 1.],
     [0., 1., 1.]]]
```

and

```
Y = [[0.1, 0.2],
    [0.3, 0.4]]
```

then `Z` should be

```
Z = [[[0.1, 0.2, 0.],
     [0.3, 0.4, 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 0.1, 0.2],
     [0., 0.3, 0.4],
     [0., 0., 0.]],

    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0.1, 0.2],
     [0., 0.3, 0.4]]]
```

I would like to do this using functions either from Numpy or Pytorch. I thought it might be possible to do this using `numpy.where()`, perhaps as

```
Z = numpy.zeros((3,3,3))
Z[numpy.where(X == 1)] = Y
```

but this gives a shape mismatch error.

What would be the most concise and efficient way to do this (apart from explicitly using loops to set the values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
X[X == 1] = np.tile(Y.flatten(), X.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the numerical example, you can use:

```
Z[X==1] = np.tile(Y.reshape(-1,),3)
Z

array([[[0.1, 0.2, 0. ],
       [0.3, 0.4, 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. ]],

       [[0. , 0.1, 0.2],
        [0. , 0.3, 0.4],
        [0. , 0. , 0. ]],

       [[0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0.1, 0.2],
        [0. , 0.3, 0.4]]])
```

For the general case you only need to substitute `K` in the place of 3 in `np.tile`.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the mask to an index and then reshape to leverage broadcasting:

```
idx = *np.reshape(X.nonzero(),(3,3,2,2)),
Z = np.zeros_like(X)
Z[idx] = Y
Z
array([[[0.1, 0.2, 0. ],
        [0.3, 0.4, 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. ]],

       [[0. , 0.1, 0.2],
        [0. , 0.3, 0.4],
        [0. , 0. , 0. ]],

       [[0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0.1, 0.2],
        [0. , 0.3, 0.4]]])
```

or the same using flat indexing:

```
idx = X.ravel().nonzero()[0].reshape(3,4)
Z = np.zeros_like(X)
Z.ravel()[idx] = Y.ravel()
```